# Can't get access to BTRFS mount point

Tags: btrfs

Hello I had communication issues between storage HP D6000 and my server ( running in redhat 7.3). 
My HP D6000 server provide a /dev/sdc which is formated in BTRFS

Indeed from my server I did not have anymore access to some file or folder, when trying to read/open them we had got an input error from linux.

By looking at system log using dmesg command, we have seen that a lot of error messages were related to btrfs . See dmesg_btrfs.log

Extract from this file :

```
perf: interrupt took too long (9676 > 8336), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 20000
[36043.474482] hrtimer: interrupt took 782069 ns
[45613.776747] perf: interrupt took too long (13318 > 12095), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 15000
[59574.767389] perf: interrupt took too long (19569 > 16647), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 10000
[68497.570082] TCP: lp registered
[86505.422816] perf: interrupt took too long (25441 > 24461), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 7000
[171641.453450] perf: interrupt took too long (32417 > 31801), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 6000
[193721.441542] perf: interrupt took too long (41771 > 40521), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 4000
[1028175.785324] st 7:0:1:0: [st0] Block limits 1 - 16777215 bytes.
[1028175.791909] st 7:0:3:0: [st1] Block limits 1 - 16777215 bytes.
[1150515.339888] mgag200 0000:01:00.1: Video card doesn't support cursors with partial transparency.
[1150515.339897] mgag200 0000:01:00.1: Not enabling hardware cursor.
[1375086.203436] perf: interrupt took too long (52220 > 52213), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 3000
[3548656.534574] hpsa 0000:0a:00.0: Controller lockup detected: 0x00130000 after 30
[3548656.534686] hpsa 0000:0a:00.0: failed 0 commands in fail_all
[3548741.513700] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513711] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.513716] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.513725] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 1, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513747] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513752] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 60 52 d0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[3548741.513755] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881849552
[3548741.513759] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 2, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513765] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 173268994 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.513778] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513782] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 62 ec 40 00 00 00 08 00 00
[3548741.513786] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987506974720 csum 3098159416 wanted 1603646717 mirror 0
[3548741.513790] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3882019904
[3548741.513794] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 3, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513805] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513810] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ea 79 b1 30 00 00 07 08 00 00
[3548741.513812] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3933843760
[3548741.513816] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 4, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513821] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 5, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513825] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 6, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513829] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 7, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513833] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 8, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513837] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 9, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513841] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 10, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548741.513891] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513896] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.513899] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.513968] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.513973] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.513976] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.513989] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987594194944 csum 1776423886 wanted 1603646717 mirror 0
[3548741.514007] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128107520 csum 170030215 wanted 1463371087 mirror 0
[3548741.514017] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128054272 csum 2035207369 wanted 3875831614 mirror 0
[3548741.514020] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.514026] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128160768 csum 3364622034 wanted 2643208738 mirror 0
[3548741.514028] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.514033] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.514037] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128214016 csum 1675650207 wanted 1213911733 mirror 0
[3548741.514053] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128267264 csum 27555141 wanted 2453508120 mirror 0
[3548741.514063] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 1633128436 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.514065] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128373760 csum 557919559 wanted 569733890 mirror 0
[3548741.514073] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128427008 csum 1371240989 wanted 83717421 mirror 0
[3548741.514077] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.514085] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128480256 csum 1526604658 wanted 3866177562 mirror 0
[3548741.514086] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.514090] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.514093] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128533504 csum 1879008678 wanted 4204609935 mirror 0
[3548741.514123] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1309577821 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.514124] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.514129] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.514132] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.514141] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1064273164 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.514186] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548741.514194] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 e7 5c 18 10 00 00 00 10 00 00
[3548741.514198] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3881572368
[3548741.514523] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 256608303 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515252] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1668274311 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515542] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 902730990 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515572] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1115285945 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515576] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 716758724 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515583] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 358114328 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515603] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 3636549634 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515606] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 2140931699 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515613] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 256515817 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515622] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 3531757333 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515639] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 971119806 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515642] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 3704890404 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515649] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 918006549 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515658] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 714113320 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.515664] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987097100288 csum 1115550596 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515672] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987103588352 csum 2268462099 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515675] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987107471360 csum 2776111913 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515682] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1989681348608 csum 4049320451 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515688] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1990118744064 csum 1081079337 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515692] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1990754316288 csum 1859145453 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515699] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1992622735360 csum 2739240806 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515704] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1992898916352 csum 1166447837 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515711] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1992902459392 csum 1143258696 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515713] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1992902463488 csum 3303908291 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515721] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1993677737984 csum 3282417549 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515724] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1993975832576 csum 1377734740 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515730] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1995046785024 csum 348194334 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515735] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1995501101056 csum 2277188112 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515739] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1995867832320 csum 3762764451 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515744] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1996122009600 csum 1007006270 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.515748] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128979968 csum 1632360799 wanted 1511955960 mirror 0
[3548741.515753] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129033216 csum 318062173 wanted 2468939300 mirror 0
[3548741.515758] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129086464 csum 2741982513 wanted 4093664990 mirror 0
[3548741.515763] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129139712 csum 94933914 wanted 2121261667 mirror 0
[3548741.515769] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129192960 csum 2943955701 wanted 3726760867 mirror 0
[3548741.515779] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129246208 csum 3566649403 wanted 1027002066 mirror 0
[3548741.515783] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129299456 csum 2028547140 wanted 3373190259 mirror 0
[3548741.515790] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129352704 csum 3934724649 wanted 2256718933 mirror 0
[3548741.515793] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129405952 csum 2297296363 wanted 2197029457 mirror 0
[3548741.515804] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129459200 csum 2707724304 wanted 3640130939 mirror 0
[3548741.515807] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129512448 csum 1405474328 wanted 496759377 mirror 0
[3548741.515812] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014129528832 csum 2645708449 wanted 4246505309 mirror 0
[3548741.516176] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1996628942848 csum 1488576545 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.516190] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1996999086080 csum 80804291 wanted 1010640845 mirror 0
[3548741.516196] BTRFS info (device sdc): no csum found for inode 341023 start 6029312
[3548741.517404] BTRFS info (device sdc): no csum found for inode 341023 start 6160384
[3548741.518424] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 4118416751 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.518693] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2000007999488 csum 4107263862 wanted 0 mirror 0
[3548741.518709] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2002565550080 csum 4154377049 wanted 0 mirror 0
[3548741.518722] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2566472073 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518737] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2566472073 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518751] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2566472073 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518755] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2566472073 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518768] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2566472073 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518772] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 604090523 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518785] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2797361829 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518790] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 3203354626 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518802] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 73308152 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518805] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 2352805398 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518812] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 91327287 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518818] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 3691543039 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518823] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 170030215 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518830] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 8928857 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518834] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 3788513356 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.518840] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 2014128320512 csum 937281625 wanted 1542107502 mirror 0
[3548741.533713] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1564583081 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.548610] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 2332273450 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.563292] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1545308022 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.576878] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 603843239 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.591413] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1971834851 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.605611] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1057867319 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.619793] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1004100376 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.634169] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 958765446 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.646489] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1510863567 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.660382] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 2141133356 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.674396] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1244115087 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.688017] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 2942545047 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.702049] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1129689245 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.716204] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 126023561 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.730635] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 529386886 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.746377] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 1458650621 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.761319] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 3255414352 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.774778] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 247657134 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548741.789581] BTRFS info (device sdc): csum failed ino 341023 extent 1987365060608 csum 3461008084 wanted 2271511096 mirror 0
[3548771.182410] scsi_io_completion: 72 callbacks suppressed
[3548771.182429] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548771.182438] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce cc 7f 60 00 00 00 20 00 00
[3548771.182442] blk_update_request: 72 callbacks suppressed
[3548771.182445] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3469508448
[3548771.182450] btrfs_dev_stat_print_on_error: 94 callbacks suppressed
[3548771.182457] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 105, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548771.182482] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548771.182486] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce cc 7f 20 00 00 00 20 00 00
[3548771.182489] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3469508384
[3548771.182493] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 106, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548771.182532] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548771.182537] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce dc 7f 20 00 00 00 20 00 00
[3548771.182540] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3470556960
[3548771.182544] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 107, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548771.182675] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548771.182685] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce cc 7f 20 00 00 00 20 00 00
[3548771.182690] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3469508384
[3548771.182696] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 108, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548771.182800] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3548771.182806] sd 7:1:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 ce dc 7f 20 00 00 00 20 00 00
[3548771.182809] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3470556960
[3548771.182813] BTRFS error (device sdc): bdev /dev/sdc errs: wr 0, rd 109, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[3548771.182896] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[3548771.182937] WARNING: at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:6552 __btrfs_free_extent.isra.66+0x825/0xd20 [btrfs]()
[3548771.182940] BTRFS: Transaction aborted (error -5)
[3548771.182942] Modules linked in: tcp_lp xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 tun bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter fuse ext4 mbcache jbd2 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod intel_powerclamp coretemp intel_rapl iosf_mbi kvm_intel kvm irqbypass osst crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ch btrfs ipmi_ssif zlib_deflate hpilo aesni_intel iTCO_wdt lrw hpwdt gf128mul ipmi_devintf glue_helper raid6_pq ablk_helper cryptd sb_edac xor st iTCO_vendor_support sg pcspkr edac_core ipmi_si ntb lpc_ich ipmi_msghandler ioatdma acpi_power_meter wmi shpchp pcc_cpufreq nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc ip_tables xfs libcrc32c
[3548771.183020]  sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic mgag200 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32c_intel syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops serio_raw ttm ahci libahci drm libata ixgbe i2c_core tg3 mdio hpsa dca scsi_transport_sas ptp pps_core fjes
[3548771.183056] CPU: 11 PID: 1123 Comm: btrfs-transacti Not tainted 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1
[3548771.183060] Hardware name: HP ProLiant ML350p Gen8, BIOS P72 08/02/2014
[3548771.183063]  ffff88101f1efb38 0000000009f8d222 ffff88101f1efaf0 ffffffff816861ac
[3548771.183068]  ffff88101f1efb28 ffffffff81085940 ffff88006add7d40 000001aa177a0000
[3548771.183073]  00000000fffffffb 0000000000000000 ffff88101c4c4000 ffff88101f1efb90
[3548771.183077] Call Trace:
[3548771.183090]  [<ffffffff816861ac>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[3548771.183098]  [<ffffffff81085940>] warn_slowpath_common+0x70/0xb0
[3548771.183103]  [<ffffffff810859dc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[3548771.183123]  [<ffffffffa07844e5>] __btrfs_free_extent.isra.66+0x825/0xd20 [btrfs]
[3548771.183153]  [<ffffffffa07f015a>] ? btrfs_merge_delayed_refs+0x9a/0x5c0 [btrfs]
[3548771.183177]  [<ffffffffa07884a5>] __btrfs_run_delayed_refs.constprop.71+0xa25/0x1200 [btrfs]
[3548771.183196]  [<ffffffffa07869cb>] ? btrfs_block_rsv_release+0x3b/0x50 [btrfs]
[3548771.183205]  [<ffffffff811de24a>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x1ba/0x1e0
[3548771.183224]  [<ffffffffa078ba97>] btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x87/0x2c0 [btrfs]
[3548771.183247]  [<ffffffffa07a1d2c>] btrfs_commit_transaction+0x4ac/0xaa0 [btrfs]
[3548771.183268]  [<ffffffffa079caa5>] transaction_kthread+0x1b5/0x240 [btrfs]
[3548771.183289]  [<ffffffffa079c8f0>] ? btrfs_cleanup_transaction+0x560/0x560 [btrfs]
[3548771.183296]  [<ffffffff810b064f>] kthread+0xcf/0xe0
[3548771.183302]  [<ffffffff810b0580>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
[3548771.183309]  [<ffffffff81696718>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
[3548771.183314]  [<ffffffff810b0580>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
[3548771.183317] ---[ end trace 9ee991c8d171f062 ]---
```

We have succeed to make the HPD6000 work again by doing the following :

```
Comment /dev/sdc in fstab
Reboot server
Launch btrfsck –readonly /dev/sdc > No error found
mount /dev/sdc and we were able to access to all files correctly.
```

We are using BTRFS-progs V4.4.1

Is my BTRFS problem is an known problem for a 4.4.1 version ? Should I update  to the last version ?

Comment: ? There’s no error where BTRFS was the root cause. All errors stem from the fact that `sdc` is gone. Fix/stabilize your storage connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I don't how how my connection to the storage can fail, I'm directly connected through a SAS connection. Maybe Redhat bug or Storage hardware failure ? Do you have any tips ?